# What int value gets used for ServletRequestAttributes scope?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

How does one know what value to give for the `scope` parameter when requesting an attribute value from a `ServletRequestAttributes` object?

In particular, I would like to get the value of the `_csrf` attribute of a request sent to the Authorization Endpoint of [this GitHub example app](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2/authserver).  I have a `CustomOAuth2RequestFactory` set up to contain the call to the `ServletRequestAttributes.getAttribute("_csrf", scope)` method, but how do I know what value to enter as the `scope` in order to get the correct `_csrf` value?

Here is [a link to the API](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/ServletRequestAttributes.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-int-).

Also, I found [this link to the Spring documentation for bean scopes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html), but how should one reference one of the scopes in the method call shown above?  Simply typing in the String name of a scope results in a compilation error warning in eclipse for trying to pass a String as an int.

Comment: These are not bean scopes. They are an abstraction of Servlet scopes (request/session). The constants are defined in the `RequestAttributes` interface. Use the one that is appropriate, request or session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term *scope* used with `ServletRequestAttributes` is unrelated to bean scopes.

[`ServletRequestAttributes`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/ServletRequestAttributes.html) defines scope as one of *request* and *session*

> Accesses objects from servlet request and HTTP session scope, with no
>   distinction between "session" and "global session".

It provides access to request and session attributes through these possible `scope` values. Constants for these are defined in [`RequestAttributes`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestAttributes.html), `SCOPE_REQUEST` and `SCOPE_SESSION`.

---

Note that the current implementation of `ServletRequestAttributes` only ever considers two scenarios. Either you provide `SCOPE_REQUEST` and it attempts to find a request attribute or you provide any other value (not necessarily `SCOPE_SESSION`), it ignores it, and attempts to find a session attribute.

Other `RequestAttributes` implementations may use different `scope` values.